# Twitter bootstrap:Popop are not showing up on first click but show up on second click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popup

Here is my code. Please help me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).delegate(".view","click",function(){

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
    $("#"+id).popover({
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
          return $("#"+id+"tt").html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('#popoverTitle').html();
        }
    });
    alert("thisa");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the function .delegate() by .on(), this function has been superseded in the last versions of Jquery.

jQuery 1.4.3+

```
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
```

jQuery 1.7+

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

The code would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".view",function(){

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
    $("#"+id).popover({
        html : true, 
        content: function() {
          return $("#"+id+"tt").html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('#popoverTitle').html();
        }
    });
    alert("thisa");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way..

```
$('.view')
.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
    .click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('pop')) {
        $(this)
        .popover('hide')
        .removeClass('pop');
    } else {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var title = $('#popoverTitle').html();
        var response = $("#"+id+"tt").html();
        $(this)
        .attr({'title': title, 'data-content': response})
        .popover('show')
        .addClass('pop');
    }
});
```